# Execute the slideup/slidedown when call the show/hide method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute the slideUp/slideDown method when I am calling the $("#divid").show() or $("#divid").hide() method.

I am trying to modify the jQuery1.10.2 version like below

```
 show: function () {
        genFx("show");

        alert("show function execute");
    },
    hide: function () {
        //alert("hide function execute");

        genFx("hide");

    },
```

Comment: why don't you use .slideup() and .slideDown() jqery methods.http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: @Sandeeproop, because, my whole project we are used the show and hide method, it is very difficult to change whole module. So I have planed to change the jQuery plugin directly.

Comment: You really don't want to execute slideDown/slideUp when calling show/hide, because slideDown and slideUp are implemented to call show and hide, respectively, when the animation is done. That would start an infinite loop of sliding up or down.